# Wordpress 4.1 - Changed Site Language & now 500 Internal Error when trying to login

Tags: wordpress

I changed the 'Site Language' in the backend of a site from US English to CA English and now I am getting a 500 Internal server error when trying to login through the backend. Because of this, I cannot change the language back.

How can I regain access to my WP dashboard?

Just wondering if there is something I could revert to within the database (site_Language) as a default? Hoping there is an answer out there - don't want to re-install..

Cheers!

Comment: What does it say in your server's error log?

Comment: Strange... 

20150114T121844: www.example.com/wp-admin/index.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 41943040 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 311296 bytes) in /hermes/bosoraweb012/b119/nf.exampleorg/public_html/wp-includes/SimplePie/Item.php on line 1490

This is the error I see within the log. When i goto /wp-admin I can view my login screen but when trying to login, I get the 500 in return.

Comment: FIXED - Added `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );` within wp-config. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

MAGIC!!

FIXED - Added define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' ); within wp-config in increase the memory limit. Have never run into this issue in 30+ sites.. SimplePie include was throwing a fatal error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the global variable in the wp-config.php:

```
define ('WPLANG', 'en_CA');
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. I have already tried this a few days ago from my own past knowledge but did not work. I do not believe it has anything to do with the wp-config file but more of "something did OR didn't" write properly within the database... I hope..

Answer (score 0):

FIXED - Added `define( 'WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '96M' );` within wp-config in increase the memory limit. Have never run into this issue in 30+ sites.. SimplePie include was throwing a fatal error.